# index array out of bounds I don't know why please helpp

Tags: java

I am sorry, I am kinda of newbie in java. My program

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String mystring = "abcdefgh";
        char[] mychars = mystring.toCharArray();
        for(int i=0;i<mychars.length;i++){
            System.out.println(mychars[i+1]);
        }
    }
```

gives me

```
b
c
d
e
f
g
h
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 8
at myfirstjavaclass.main(myfirstjavaclass.java:9)
```

why it's not starting from a?

thanks

Comment: -----------> `mychars[i+1]` ------------>`[i+1]` ------------->`+1`

Comment: there are 2 complex problems in computer science 1) cache invalidation, 2) naming things, 3) off-by-one errors

Comment: Both of your problems are occurring because the first element of any Java array is indexed 0.  So `myChars[0]` is `a`, `myChars[1]` is `b` and so on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because Java Starts to count Indexes at 0. replace the 1+i in your code with simply i and it will work. Like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String mystring = "abcdefgh";
    char[] mychars = mystring.toCharArray();
    for(int i=0;i<mychars.length;i++){
        System.out.println(mychars[i]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

because `System.out.println(mychars[i+1]);` is outside the bounds of the array when `i` is at the last index in the array.

It is the `i+1` part that is causeing the exception